# Monogame-uwp package can´t be published to the Windows Store because it still targets Windows.Mobile and can´t be enrypted because of that

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml, windows-10-universal, monogame

I´m trying to publish a package (which is build with the normal uwp-template from monogame) to the Windows Store and it shows the following message:

```
The package abcdefg_1.0.8.0_x86_x64_bundle.appxupload can’t be encrypted because it targets 
the Windows.Mobile platform, which does not support encryption. The package will be encrypted 
in your sandbox environments, but it will be published unencrypted to the Store.
```

Which leads to Microsoft asking me this:

```
The Target Device Family in the AppxManifest is set to Windows.Universal but that
means that your game can’t be encrypted due to Windows.Mobile not supporting it. Please set 
the Target Device Family to Windows.Xbox and Windows.Desktop
instead so that your build can be encrypted and then resubmit the new build.
```

If I set the target to Windows.Desktop (in Appx_Manifest setting TargetDeviceFamily to Name="Windows.Desktop") it still compiles and builds fine but the store shows me a few new errors like these:

```
Validation error: FrameworkDependencyVersionConflict - 10.0.0.0, Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00 14.0.30704.0, 10.0.10042.0
Validation error: FrameworkDependencyVersionConflict - 10.0.0.0, Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00 14.0.30704.0, 10.0.10042.0
Validation error: FrameworkDependencyVersionConflict - 10.0.0.0, Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.2.2 2.2.29512.0, 10.0.10049.0
Validation error: FrameworkDependencyVersionConflict - 10.0.0.0, Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.2.2 2.2.29512.0, 10.0.10049.0
Validation error: FrameworkDependencyVersionConflict - 10.0.0.0, Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.2 2.2.28604.0, 10.0.10049.0
Validation error: FrameworkDependencyVersionConflict - 10.0.0.0, Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.2 2.2.28604.0, 10.0.10049.0
```

Is there maybe a way to just remove windows.mobile from the uwp-build or maybe an easier way to target just Windows.Desktop and Windows.Xbox? Or is there an easy way to fix the FrameworkdependencyVersionConflict?

Thank you,

Harry

Comment: You might need to change the minversion in the project file like `<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.10049.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.10049.0" />`

Comment: That fixed it. For Windows.Xbox the minVersion has to be 10.0.14000.0. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the minversion in the project file to the version the error message mentioned.

Like this:

```
<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.10049.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.10049.0" />
```